# Broken https because of non-https elements?

Tags: html, http, ssl, https

I own an forums application, and whenever someone posts some content that is linked as non-https, chrome is crying that https is broken or something, because page contains non-secured content. Is there anything I can do about it? Basically to keep that https in the address bar greeen, i would need to deny my users of posting anything that comes from the other pages, and that's crazy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a link redirector. When they post a url, you use a link like https://yoursite.com/redirect/user_posted_url

I don't know what forum plataform are you using.

Comment: Oh! That could work! Thanks! :)